# Laravel Websockets on vps serve

Tags: laravel, centos7, laravel-websockets

I install [laravel websockets](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/)
is working fine in localhost when i upload in server (inmotionhosting, Centos7) is not work

brodcasting.php

```
  'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => 'rdms.sawagroup.org',
                'port' => 8443,
                'scheme' => 'https',
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ]         
            ],
        ],
```

websockets.php

```
           'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => true,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
            'encrypted' => true,
```

main.js

```
 window.Pusher = require('pusher-js')
            window.Echo = new Echo({
              broadcaster: 'pusher',
              key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
              cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
              encrypted: true,
              wsHost: window.location.hostname,
              wsPort: 8443,
              wssPort: 8443,
              forceTLS: true,
              disableStats: false,
              enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
              authorizer: channel => ({
                authorize: (socketId, callback) => {
                  axios.post('/api/broadcasting/auth', {
                    socket_id: socketId,
                    channel_name: channel.name,
                  })
                    .then(response => {
                      callback(false, response.data)
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                      callback(true, error)
                    })
                },
              }),
            })
```

i read documentation but i don't understand how can get pem files

Comment: Did you figure it out?
Having the same problem since 3 days now...

Comment: @leonnicklas yes i solved

Comment: How did you solve it if I may ask?

Comment: @leonnicklas i contact with support center of my host and give me key and certificate